# microphone in windows 10 in virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, microphone, cortana

I have installed the Build 9926 of the windows 10 technical preview i.e The January Build, on Windows 7.

I am trying to use the voice assistance of cortana on my Virtuabox but am not able to do so.
The microphone works perfectly fine on my host windows 7 machine

Any suggestions as to should i do so that my microphone works in virtualBox??

Comment: Great question, helped me a lot!

Comment: It might be slightly off-topic, but it is the single most helpful resource on this topic (crackling audio, both in and out). Relevant link to track the source issue: Virtualbox ticket [#15925 (Crackling sound...)](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15925)

Answer (score 41):

1. In VirtualBox open the settings for your Windows 10 machine
2. Go to Audio > Audio Controller, change to "ICH AC97"
3. [Boot your Windows 10 machine and disable driver signature enforcement](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/)
4. Go to [Realtek's website](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-ac-97-audio-codecs-software), download and install the AC'97 audio codec/driver for Vista/7 ("Vista/Win7 (32/64 bits) Driver only (ZIP file)") onto your Windows 10 machine (run setup.exe after unzipping)
5. Reboot Windows 10 and you should be done

Comment: mic work but there are no sound when i test the sound error poped up `failed to play test tone` to test it i right click on sound icon on windows tray then choose playback devices then choose speakers and click on properties goto  advanced and click on test

Comment: works like a charm. Both audio input and output works now.

Comment: Hmm I did get this to work, but didn't get audio input to work with this (but that's from a mac which may be related).  As a side note, if you change your virtualbox audio setting to "Intel HD Audio" instead of "ICH AC97" then audio seems to start working without driver install required...

Comment: Beautiful... you saved me!

Comment: Thanks for this. Even though it's off topic, you saved me from having to reboot every time I want to skype.

Comment: the AC'97 audio driver is not installable in my windows 10.

Comment: Only works if you disable the Signed Driver Enforcement

Comment: Didn't work for me :-(  AC97 is just as bad as the default Intel HD Audio device.

Comment: Realtek's link is dead now.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs it works as of now. Although, it requires you give them e-mail to receive link. Also, the link will only work for 5 minutes. If you can't download it from Realtek website, try searching for `0001-6305_Vista_Win7_PG537.zip` - that's the archive containing the driver.

Comment: I have used disposable e-mail to download their driver, but this turned out to be unnecessary - they did not ask to confirm it, so I guess anything can be typed in if it looks like e-mail address.

Comment: Works - you're a genius -- note: do not click setup.exe in the zip -- do a full proper extract and then run setup.exe.

Comment: Not work for me with Windows 10 and latest VirtualBox 6.1. It had selected AC97 Audio, disabled code signing mode, downloaded and installed AC97 Audio Drive for Vista/Win7_64 and reboot the Windows 10 Host. Nothing worked for me :(

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62330478/2224647