# VirtualBox - no sound on Guest Win10

Tags: virtualbox

Recently I installed VirtualBox 6.1 on my MacBook Air and installed Windows 10 on it (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/), but somehow the sound on my guest Win10 is not working. I managed to dig for some info and found out that I need to install (https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-ac-97-audio-codecs-software) but it does not work. Could anybody help me with this one?

EDIT: I get the error when I hover over the sound icon: "no audio output device is installed"

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1106839/audio-not-working-in-win-10-in-virtualbox-virtualbox-5-1-2-guest-additions-m

Answer (score 9):

I tried the route in the most upvoted answer but couldn't get Win10 to install the AC97 driver. For me the solution was much simpler: select Audio Controller "Intel HD Audio" in the virtual machine settings (and leave Host Audio Driver to whatever the default was, in my case "Pulse Audio"). Enable Audio Output checked of course, and it should just work like the machine has a sound card.

Crackling is still there even with the stuff about turning off enhancements and exclusivity, but I think that's not going away since I'm trying to play 1080p video and I don't think the virtual machine has quite the kind of video hardware access (and memory allocation) that it needs to play this level of content perfectly smoothly.

Comment: This also worked quite well for me and I don't have issues with crackling sounds. Way simpler solution than installing a driver.

Answer (score 7):

## **Fixing the sound on guest windows 10 where the host is Linux / Mac**

- Open the settings for your Windows 10 machine inside of virtualbox
- Go to Audio > Host Audio Driver, change to "ALSA Audio Driver"
- Go to Audio > Audio Controller, change to "ICH AC97"
- Enable [Test Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/) on Windows 10 and reboot machine.
- Download and install the Realtek driver for *Vista/Win7 (32/64 bits) Driver only (ZIP file)* from [here](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-ac-97-audio-codecs-software) and reboot your Windows 10 machine.
- Disable test mode from the link in 4th step then reboot your Windows 10 machine.

---

#### In case you still have a crackling / popping sound

- In the task bar, right click on the sound icon and choose playback devices
- Double click on Speakers
- Select the Advanced Tab
- Set the Default Format to 16 bit, 44100 Hz (CD Quality)
- In the Exclusive Mode, Uncheck the Allow applications... etc
- Select the Enhancement Tab
- Check the Disable all sound effects
- Make sure you click apply then OK

The crackling sound would immediately disappear but you could reboot just to verify.

Comment: For me ALSA + Intel HD fix sound problem

Answer (score 2):

Install Guest Additions if you haven't already.  More info here for your specific case: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows

Comment: I'm kinda confused, from the list in a link you provided, should I check for Windows or MacOS since I'm using Mac, but in my VM in use Windows

Comment: @rottenbanana you should follow the directions based on your guest (VM) OS, so in this case, Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the fix above, and eventually got my VBox working again. My Host Audio Driver was set in Linux Mint to Pulse Audio, and the controller was set to Intel HD Audio. I changed the Host Audio Driver to Alsa, and the controller to AC97. Then downloaded and tried to install the RealTek driver. It wouldn't install. So I reverted the controller to Intel HD Audio and the driver to Pulse Audio, then everything started working again.

I absolutely hate Windows!

Answer (score 0):

With Fedora 36 host and Windows Server 22 Standard Desktop Evaluation as guest inside VirtualBox 6.1.34 it automagically worked after enabling sound at guest via:

1. Mouse Right Klick at (disabled) speakers symbol in Windows taskbar
2. Mouse Left Klick at "Sounds" (German)

-> [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEhIN.png)

Accepting the prompt enabled sound with all default settings in VirtualBox VM Audio Settings:

- Host Driver: ALSA Audio Driver
- Controller: Intel HD Audio

VirtualBox 6.1.34 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack was also already installed here.

Sound tested successfully with Firefox 100 and https://fip.fr -> Rock